# SQLite Python; writing a value that populates a grid from a slider to the database

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

I want to populate a SQLite database with a value from a slider widget. I can update a cell using the keyboard but I can't get it to work when the cell is populated from the slider. I am using a button to trigger the population and the write to the database but when I click it, I get a 'sqlite3.OperationError: near "0": syntax error. Here is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
import sqlite3

class Grid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent, db):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateGrid(10,5)

        for row in range(10):
            rowNum = row + 1
            self.SetRowLabelValue(row, "cue %s" %rowNum)

        self.db = db
        self.cur = self.db.con.cursor()

        meta = self.cur.execute("SELECT * from CUES")
        labels = []
        for i in meta.description:
            labels.append(i[0])
        labels = labels[1:]
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            self.SetColLabelValue(i, labels[i])

        all = self.cur.execute("SELECT * from CUES ORDER by DTindex")
        for row in all:
            row_num = row[0]
            cells = row[1:]
            for i in range(len(cells)):
                if cells[i] != None and cells[i] != "null":
                    self.SetCellValue(row_num, i, str(cells[i]))

        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED, self.CellContentsChanged)

    def CellContentsChanged(self, event):
        x = event.GetCol()
        y = event.GetRow()
        val = self.GetCellValue(y,x)
        if val == "":
            val = "null"
        ColLabel = self.GetColLabelValue(x)
        InsertCell = "UPDATE CUES SET %s = ? WHERE DTindex = %d"%(ColLabel,y)
        self.cur.execute(InsertCell, [(val),]) 
        self.db.con.commit()
        self.SetCellValue(y, x, val)

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, db):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Grid plus db", size = (800,600))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.db = db
        self.cur = self.db.con.cursor()

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=10, hgap=10)

        self.slide1 = wx.Slider(panel, -1, 0, 0, 255, size=(50,400),
                                  style=wx.SL_VERTICAL|wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_LABELS|wx.SL_INVERSE)
        self.slide1.SetTickFreq(10)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL_CHANGED, self.onReport, self.slide1)
        self.slide2 = wx.Slider(panel, -1, 0, 0, 255, size=(50,400),
                                 style=wx.SL_VERTICAL|wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_LABELS|wx.SL_INVERSE)
        self.slide2.SetTickFreq(10)

        self.grid = Grid(panel,db)

        self.display = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, size=(200,100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.aBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Grid")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPopulate, self.aBtn)

        self.bBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Database")

        sizer.Add(self.slide1, pos=(0,0))
        sizer.Add(self.slide2, pos=(0,1))
        sizer.Add(self.grid, pos = (0,2))
        sizer.Add(self.aBtn, pos=(1,0))
        sizer.Add(self.display, pos=(1,1), span=(2,2))
        sizer.Add(self.bBtn, pos=(2,0))

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        panel.Fit()

    def onReport(self,event):
        val = self.slide1.GetValue()
        self.display.WriteText("Slide 1 value = %s\n"%val)

    def onPopulate(self, event):
        """Work in Progress"""
        val = str(self.slide1.GetValue()) + '\n'
        #put a dlg here to get row col - place in SetCellValue(x,y,....
        self.grid.SetCellValue(0,0, val) #gets it to the grid...Need to write it to the database       
        InsertCell = "UPDATE CUES SET %s = ? WHERE DTindex = %d"%(0,0)
        self.cur.execute(InsertCell, [(val),])
        self.db.con.commit()

class GetDatabase():
    def __init__(self, f):
        try:
            file = open(f)
            file.close()
        except IOError:
            self.exists = 0
        else:
            self.exists = 1
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    db = GetDatabase("data.db")
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame(None, db)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The database was created in DB Browser for SQLite:
 CREATE TABLE `CUES` (
    `DTindex`   INTEGER,
    `A` string,
    `B` string,
    `C` string,
    `D` string,
    `E` string,
    PRIMARY KEY(`DTindex`)
);

Comment: As you have not defined the structure of the database in the code and you haven't specified what it is, it is not possible to run this code. As such it's difficult to know what is going wrong.

Comment: The database is a seperate file. I've added the table definitions. The database will update if I add a value to a cell using the keyboard. It won't update the database if I add a value to a cell using 'self.grid.SetCellValue(0,0,val)'. I have done many searches on the error and it seems that there are many reason for this error. Thank you @Rolf_of_Saxony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's a simple error in this line:

```
InsertCell = "UPDATE CUES SET %s = ? WHERE DTindex = %d"%(0,0)
```

`0` whilst a valid value for `DTindex` is a not a valid value for a column name, which would be A,B,C,D or E.
Without knowing exactly what you are attempting to achieve, the following will function.

```
InsertCell = "UPDATE CUES SET %s = ? WHERE DTindex = %d"%('A',0)
```

But only if you have a record with a `DTindex` of 0 (zero), where it replaces the value of the column A with the value from your slider

Comment: Worked perfectly. Knew it had to be something simple. Thank you @Rolf_of_Saxony